# Get Properties from Toggleswitch in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am looking for a way to access the toggleswitch's properties value in code behind.
Some properties have text I want to translate. To make it possible I used an interesting function I got on the net.
Example with normal labels :

```
List<Label> label_list = GetLogicalChildCollection<Label>(_contour.ContourGrid);
        for (int i = 0; i < label_list.Count; i++)
        {

            if (Translator.HasProperty(label_list[i], "Content"))
            {

                var _valuefromProperty = label_list[i].GetType().GetProperty("Content");
                string value = _valuefromProperty.GetValue(label_list[i], null) as string;
                Translator.SetProperty(label_list[i], "Content", _translation.Translate(value));



            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work when the element is a ToggleSwitch developed with the framework MahApps.

The code behind I use is approximately the same as before :

```
 List<ToggleSwitch> toggle_list = GetLogicalChildCollection<ToggleSwitch>(_contour.ContourGrid);
        for (int i = 0; i < label_list.Count; i++)
        {

            if (Translator.HasProperty(toggle_list[i], "OffLabel"))
            {

                var _valueOff = label_list[i].GetType().GetProperty("OffLabel");
                string value_off_str = _valueOff.GetValue(toggle_list[i], null) as string;
                Translator.SetProperty(label_list[i], "OffLabel", _translation.Translate(value_off_str));


                var _valueOn = label_list[i].GetType().GetProperty("OnLabel");
                string value_on_str = _valueOn.GetValue(label_list[i], null) as string;
                Translator.SetProperty(label_list[i], "OnLabel", _translation.Translate(value_on_str));
            }
        }
```

the variable _valueOff =null. Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: OnLabel and OffLabel are DPs, why do you want to change them via reflection?

Comment: because I don't know the values in advance the users, colleagues and so on want to give.